# Different SSD Serial Number in Powershell with Different Privileges

Tags: powershell, serial-number, solid-state-drive

I run this command in my windows 10 powershell:

```
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber
```

get result with normal user permission:

```
SerialNumber
ACE4_2E81_7004_1B90.
```

get result with administrator permission:

```
SerialNumber
EJ82N176910102N4Q
```

I think `EJ82N176910102N4Q` is correct.

Why the two results are different？

Is there a way to convert `ACE4_2E81_7004_1B90.` to `EJ82N176910102N4Q`?

The command `Get-WMIObject win32_physicalmedia|Format-List Tag,SerialNumber` has the same problem.
[image]

Comment: [1] do you only have one device? my 1st suspicion would be different devices. [*grin*] [2] have you tried using one of the powershell commands instead of WMIC.exe?

Comment: I run commands in one device(Windows 10). I have tried the powershell command```Get-WMIObject win32_physicalmedia|Format-List Tag,SerialNumber```，but it has the same problem.

Comment: thank you for the added info. [*grin*] i cannot think of any reason for the problem you are having ... nor any workaround for it. [*blush*] i will go back to lurking ... good luck!

Comment: Do you also see this difference when using `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Format-List DeviceID, SerialNumber` ?

Comment: ```Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Format-List DeviceID, SerialNumber``` get the same result ```ACE4_2E81_7004_1B90.``` in two cases.

Comment: It looks like the [Win32_PhysicalMedia class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cimwin32a/win32-physicalmedia) has been superseded (as of Vista?) by the [Win32_DiskDrive class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive). I don't know why the difference in output for a normal user and the administrator. On my machine there is no difference. Maybe it has something to do with encoding or endianess?